# What does this new String[] and String.value() code mean?

Tags: java, string

I am doing some Android development and I encountered this:

```
       String[] strArray = new String[]{
           String.valueOf(1)
      };
```

Why String is created like an object and what does

```
valueOf(1)
```

actually set here ?

Comment: Tags don't go in titles. I've fixed the title for you -- removed the tag, added the `new String[]` bit so people don't drive-by-downvote for not reading the `String.valueOf` docs. (That said, [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-) *does* tell you exactly what the second part of your question asks.)

Comment: Thanks, I am new here :)

Comment: I have no idea why the code is doing what it is doing? String.valueOf(x)  takes the object/int/long etc x and turns it into a string, as the value of x is hardcoded why didn't they just String[] strArray = new String[] {"1"};

Comment: I hardcoded it for clearness. In the original code it is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
String[] strArray = new String[]{
    // ...
};
```

...creates a `String` array and initializes it with the entries in the `{...}` part. In your case, there's only one entry.

> Why String is created like an object and what does
>
> `valueOf(1);`

As [the documentation will tell you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-), `String.valueOf(int)` creates a string representation of the integer value you pass in.

So what that code does is create an array of `String` with one entry, `"1"`, in it. It's unclear why the author would have written `String.valueOf(1)` rather than simply `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.valueOf(...)
```

is a method that parses an object or a primitive, and creates a String representation of that object. For example the integer 1 will be converted to the string "1" (as in your example).

---

```
String[] strArray = new String[]{
       String.valueOf(1)
  };
```

means that we instantiate an array of Strings (basically an array that contains multiple Strings), and we add a String containing "1" in it (see my explanation above).

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet in the question looks like wrong. and I hope it should be as follows.

```
  String[] s= new String[]{
               String.valueOf(1)
          };
```

String.valueOf(1) "Returns the string representation of the int argument".

the values is returned from  " String.valueOf(1)" is assigned to the string array object. The value "1" will be stored in the 0th index.